401 received with WebClient in Spring
I am having an external API, which i am able to get the Auth Token and ping in Postman without an issue following the next steps:
    i have tested again in postman, works fine
    in Postman i use :
    
    Auth Type: OAuth 2.0
    
    Grant type: Client Credentials
    
    Access Token UR: the above
    
    Client ID:above
    
    Client Secret:above
    
    Scope: aboce
    
    Client Authentication: Send as Basic Auth headers
    
    i click "Get new token" proceed and all fine, 

then i try in Spring this method
private OAuth2AuthorizedClient obtainToken(ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
    String tokenUrl = clientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getTokenUri();
    String clientId = clientRegistration.getClientId();
    String clientSecret = clientRegistration.getClientSecret();
    String scope = "https://test.account.myconpamys/auth/gpr/.default"; // or your API's scope

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();

    // Prepare the form data including client_id and client_secret
    MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    formData.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    formData.add("client_id", clientId);
    formData.add("client_secret", clientSecret);
    formData.add("scope", scope);

    try {
        // Make the POST request
        Map<String, Object> responseBody = webClient.post()
                .uri(tokenUrl)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {})
                .block();

        if (responseBody == null || !responseBody.containsKey("access_token")) {
            // Check if the response might be nested under a different key
            if (responseBody != null && responseBody.containsKey("token")) {
                responseBody = (Map<String, Object>) responseBody.get("token");
            }
            if (responseBody == null || !responseBody.containsKey("access_token")) {
                throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(new OAuth2Error("invalid_token"), "Failed to obtain access token");
            }
        }

        // Extract the access token and other details
        String accessTokenValue = (String) responseBody.get("access_token");
        String tokenType = (String) responseBody.get("token_type");
        int expiresIn = (Integer) responseBody.get("expires_in");
        Instant issuedAt = Instant.now();
        Instant expiresAt = issuedAt.plusSeconds(expiresIn);

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = new OAuth2AccessToken(
                OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER,
                accessTokenValue,
                issuedAt,
                expiresAt,
                clientRegistration.getScopes()
        );

        return new OAuth2AuthorizedClient(clientRegistration, "my-client", 
accessToken);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log the exception, then throw an appropriate exception
        throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(new OAuth2Error("invalid_token"), 
"Failed to obtain access token: " + e.getMessage(), e);
     }
 }

but i get
 checkpoint ⇢ 401 UNAUTHORIZED from POST 
 https://login.microsoftonline.com/myid/oauth2/v2.0/token [DefaultWebClient]
|_ Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ at 

but why ?? I use the same crednetials, like scope, clientId, secret , Auth Token url in Postman and it works !! What is the difference here ?

You're using Send as Basic Auth headers for the client authentication in Postman, which means the client credentials client_id and client_secret are sent as a Basic Authentication header. But in your web client setup code, you're sending client_id and client_secret in the form data, not as Basic Authentication headers.
Add a Basic Authentication header in the WebClient request:
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .defaultHeaders(headers -> headers.setBasicAuth(clientId, clientSecret))
    .build();

And then remove client_id and client_secret from formData, as they’ll now be in the headers.
